# What is the best way to encapsulate multiple service calls using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, service, architecture

I need to call one third party service and if it succeeds, then i will call another service of my application. What is the best approach to encapsulate this calls? and ensure that its become a single transaction?

For Example, call this services in one single point:

```
public class ThirdPartyService(){

    sendProduct(){
        // Call external service
    }

}

public class ProductService(){

    confirmProduct(){
        // Do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: is the thirdpartyservice and your productservice transactional? have you looked at springs documentation? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: yes they are... only @transactional will do the job?

Comment: well if your app is not running in a jee container and the transactions span over multiple ressources (as you indicated) you also need a transaction manager implementation (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programming-model)